# parsing custom JSON in go, type determined dynamically

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON of below structure:

```
[
    {
        "option_id": "cust_info",
        "value_type": "JSON",
        "value": {
            "validForVerification": true,
            "firstLetter": "S",
            "lastLetter": "I"
        }
    },
    {
        "option_id": "settings_show_image",
        "value_type": "Boolean",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "option_id": "bonus_disabled_notified",
        "value_type": "Boolean",
        "value": false
    },
    {
        "option_id": "free_mugs_limit",
        "value_type": "Integer",
        "value": -1
    },
    {
        "option_id": "leaderboard_notification",
        "value_type": "Integer",
        "value": 17000000
    },
    {
        "option_id": "parental_control",
        "value_type": "Integer",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "option_id": "rewards_cap",
        "value_type": "Integer",
        "value": 40
    },
    {
        "option_id": "voluntary_death",
        "value_type": "Integer",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "option_id": "golden_triangle",
        "value_type": "Boolean",
        "value": false
    },
    {
        "option_id": "location_based_service_enable",
        "value_type": "Boolean",
        "value": true
    }
]
```

The `value` filed changes type depending on the `value_type` -- I tried doing this using interface{} in struct, but the problem is when I try to get an int type or when value is an object how to access internal fields like `validForVerification` etc.. I also tried parsing into map, but it fails.

I have no control on the API - so I have to live with this weird JSON.

Comment: Duplicate. Unmarshal value into a json.RawMessage during the first unmarshaling and switch on value_type to determine what type to use to unmarshal that json.RawMessage into in a second step.

Comment: Can you link the duplicate question? I will take reference from there..

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage_unmarshal

Comment: @User3 So I'm supposed to do the search work?

Comment: Nope if you hadn't marked this as a dupe I wouldn't have asked you! On a lighter note, I can well imagine what a pain you'd be to your team haha!

Comment: Thanks @Peter, thanks for pointing me a direction :)

Comment: See question [Is there a way to dynamically unmarshal json base on content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58073214/5728991) and other questions linked from there.

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón - I have solved it with the reference from @Peter!